# Get count of matching word in string of pandas column with a predefined list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, dataset

I have a `DataFrame` contains `index` and `text` columns.

For example:

```
index | text
1     | "I have a pen, but I lost it today."
2     | "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today."
```

Now I have a long list, and I want to match each of the words in `text` with the list.

Let's say:

```
long_list = ['pen', 'pineapple']
```

I would want to create a `FunctionTransformer` to match words in the `long_list` with each word of the column value, if there is a match, return the count.

```
index | text                                             | count
1     | "I have a pen, but I lost it today."             | 1
2     | "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today." | 2
```

I did in this way:

```
def count_words(df):
    long_list = ['pen', 'pineapple']
    count = 0
    for c in df['tweet_text']:
        if c in long_list:
            count = count + 1
            
    df['count'] = count   
    return df

count_word = FunctionTransformer(count_words, validate=False)
```

An example of how I develop my other `FunctionTransformer` will be:

```
def convert_twitter_datetime(df):
    df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').dt.strftime('%H').astype(int)
    return df

convert_datetime = FunctionTransformer(convert_twitter_datetime, validate=False)
```

Comment: Why not use the function `count()` in pandas?

Comment: @CeliusStingher I'm working on a pipeline, so my plan was to create a FunctionTransformer for it, but I'm open to any solution! I'm still new :3

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @Quang Hoang's answer

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk

y=['pen', 'pineapple']

def count_strings(X, y):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(y))
    return X['text'].str.count(pattern)

string_transformer = sk.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(count_strings, kw_args={'y': y})
df['count'] = string_transformer.fit_transform(X=df)
```

results in

```
    text                                              count
1   "I have a pen, but I lost it today."                1
2   "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today.     2
```

And for the following `df2`:

```
#df2
      text
1     "I have a pen, but I lost it today. pen pen"
2     "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today."
```

We get

```
string_transformer.transform(X=df2)
#result
1    3
2    2
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

This shows, that we converted the function to an `sklearn`-style object. To abstact this even further we can hand over the column name as key-word argument to `count_strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has `str.count`:

```
# matching any of the words
pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(long_list))

df['count'] = df.text.str.count(pattern)
```

Output:

```
   index                                              text  count
0      1              "I have a pen, but I lost it today."      1
1      2  "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today."      2
```

Comment: But I'm not too sure about this approach, because OP says he wants a FunctionTransformer, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html I think a function must be created

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang! Your answer has inspired others to solve my problem! Deserve an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Join elements in a list with with `|`. Find matching elements with `.str.findall()` and apply `.str.len()` for count

```
 p='|'.join(long_list)
df=df.assign(count=(df.text.str.findall(p)).str.len())
                                             text   count
0              "I have a pen, but I lost it today."      1
1  "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today."      2
```