# Count matching words and assign the count to each matching word column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I understand how to count the matching word in a pandas column with a predefined list of words and assign the count into another column (It's similar to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803265/get-count-of-matching-word-in-string-of-pandas-column-with-a-predefined-list)). But I am wondering if there's a way or a function to assign the counts to the matching word columns in column-wise style.

```
index | text
1     | "I have a pen and ipod, but I lost it today."
2     | "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today."
```

```
long_list = ['pen', 'pineapple', 'ipod']
```

```
index | text                                             | pen | pineapple | ipod |
1     | "I have a pen and ipod, but I lost it today."    | 1   |    0      |   1  |
2     | "I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today." | 1   |    1      |   0  |
```

Comment: If there are repeated words (e.g. 2) in a line, would you want to count it as 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Good question. In this context, I'd count them as 1. @SeaBean

Comment: How about partial word match ?   Should `pencil` match with `pen` ?

Comment: Another good question. Yes, I did want to bring in fuzzy matching - say `pencils` and `pencil` and `Pencils`.  @SeaBean

Comment: That's fine then.  Partial word match allowed and multiple occurrences only counted once.  The accepted solution works well on this.  :-)

Comment: Oh, you want `Pencils` to match with `pen` ?   Then, we should match ignoring case.

Comment: @SeaBean let's say this is implementation detail ;)

Comment: I don't think I'd want matching between`pencils` and `pen` but I'd love to match lowercase/uppercase for `pencils` and perhaps `pencils/pencil`. @SeaBean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a concise solution using [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [named capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups):

```
regex = '|'.join(map(lambda i: f'(?P<{i}>{i})', long_list))
df.join(df['text'].str.extract(regex).notnull().astype(int))
```

output:

```
index                                            text  pen  pineapple  ipod
    1     I have a pen and ipod, but I lost it today.    1          0     0
    2  I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today.    0          1     0
```

If the words contain invalid characters, it is also possible to use unnamed capturing groups (they will be numbered 0/1/2/3), then to rename the columns:

```
long_list = ['pen', 'pineapple', 'ipod', 'cheese cake']
regex = '|'.join(map(lambda x: f'({x})', long_list))
df.join(df['text'].str.extract(regex)
                  .notnull().astype(int)
                  .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(long_list)))
        )
```

output:

```
index              text  pen  pineapple  ipod  cheese cake
    1  I have a pen ...    1          0     0            0
    2  I have pineap...    0          1     0            0
```

##### how it works

`extract` will create a column for each capturing group with the group name as column name, the matched strings in the cells, and NaN otherwise. We then transform this output to integer using `notnull`+`astype(int)`

##### notes on the regex

*NB. the regex is in the form `'(?P<pen>pen)|(?P<pineapple>pineapple)|(?P<ipod>ipod)'`*

To ensure that whole words are matched (i.e., pencil should not match for pen), let's add word boundaries (`\b`):

```
regex = '|'.join(map(lambda i: fr'(?P<{i}>\b{i}\b)', long_list))
```

which gives: `'(?P<pen>\\bpen\\b)|(?P<pineapple>\\bpineapple\\b)|(?P<ipod>\\bipod\\b)'`

If words are used that contain spaces (or characters that are invalid in python variables), those should be replaced/removed:

```
regex = '|'.join(map(lambda i: fr'(?P<{i.replace(" ", "_")}>\b{i}\b)', long_list))
```

##### variant to *count* the occurrences

```
df.join(df['text']
          .str.extractall(regex)
          .notnull().astype(int)
          .groupby(level=0).sum()
       )
```

output (I modified the input to have twice "pen" in the first row):

```
index                                               text  pen  pineapple  ipod
    1  I have a pen and another pen an ipod, but I lo...    2          0     1
    2     I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today.    1          1     0
```

Comment: Could also add word boundary `\b` to exclude partial word match, if necessary  :-)

Comment: Well, this wouldn't work for duplicate occurences though

Comment: @U12-Forward I think this was not requested, but if needed it's easy to add this function

Comment: @mozway Yah, that's true, just use `len` and `fillna`, anyway the OP didn't request it's fine! good answer btw

Comment: You can add `(?i)` to the regex if OP wants to match IGNORECASE.    :-)

Comment: @SeaBean thanks for the suggestions (I thought of `\b` afterwards but I was already AFK)

Comment: @U12-Forward I updated the answer with a variant to count the occurrences

Comment: Hey @mozway, the solution works well until it has a word 'cheeze cake' on the list. What can I do to accomdate this two-words with a space variant?

Comment: @codedancer this is because space is not allowed in a python variable, I added a solution to escape it, this is also needed for other invalid characters, **and a general solution to use unamed capturing groups and renaming of the columns**.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pd.get_dummies` with `str.findall`:

```
>>> df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['text'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(long_list)})').explode()).groupby(level=0).sum())
   index                                            text  ipod  pen  pineapple
0      1     I have a pen and ipod, but I lost it today.     1    1          0
1      2  I have pineapple and pen, but I lost it today.     0    1          1
>>>
```

This doesn't require a for loop.

Comment: @mozway Did the same to you :P !

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `str.contains`

```
for i in long_list:
    df.loc[df.text.str.contains(i), i] = 1
```

Comment: I like your approach as it's quite succinct. But it's assigning "NaN" instead of "0" in those no count cells.

Comment: @codedancer you can always `fillna(0)` if needed, however this approach might be slow for long lists as it is looping over the elements to match (it checks the whole data for each string to match)